# Deduce that a function is zero on interval $[0,M]$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have been thinking about this for the last few days but I was not able to produce a definitive answer.

Take an integrable function $g$ that maps in $\mathbb{R}$ and with domain contained in $[0,M]$ (not necessarily equal to this interval). Consider now a family of probability measures $\mu_{\theta}$ such that $\mu_{\theta} \ll \lambda$ (Lebesgue measure) for every $\theta$. These measures have strictly positive density $f_{\theta}(z) > 0 \: \: \forall \: 0 \leq z < \theta \leq M$. The densities are not defined for $z \geq \theta$.  In symbols:

$$ \mathcal{M}_{\lambda} = \bigg\{ \mu_{\theta} \: : \: \theta \in [0,M] \: \: \text{and} \: \: \frac{d\mu_{\theta}}{d\lambda} = f_{\theta} \: : \: f_{\theta}(z) > 0 \: \: \forall \: 0 \leq z < \theta \leq M, \:\forall \: \theta \in [0,M] \bigg\}$$

**Question:** is it true that:

$$ 0 = \int_{0}^{\theta} g(z) d \mu_{\theta} (z) = \int_{0}^{\theta} g(z) \underbrace{f_{\theta}(z)}_{> 0} dz  \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \forall \: \theta \in [0,M] \: \: \: \: \: \: \stackrel{?}{\implies} \: \: \: \: \: \: g(z) = 0 \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \text{a.e. for} \: z \in [0,M]$$

As an example, you can take as $f_{\theta}(z) = \frac{\mathbb{1}_{[0,\theta)}(z)}{2 \sqrt{\theta^2 - \theta z}}$ for fixed $\theta$.

**Intuition:** I think the claim is true because the condition is true for every $\theta$ and thus can be thought as a "scanning condition". I.e. we are scanning $g$ over the whole interval $[0,M]$ by moving the $\theta$'s. Moreover, the density is always strictly positive so this makes the "scanning" meaningful.

**Proposal:** I have at the moment a proof of this statement that assumes that $g$ is continuous and have finitely many zeros. Basically I use the finitely many zeros assumption to say that $g$ cannot have infinitely many fluctuations from above to below zero and then I consider each one of these finitely many neighborhoods where $g$ is strictly positive or strictly negative (by continuity) and I show via contradiction that on that neighborhood actually $g$ must be $0$ because otherwise, we can find a $\theta$ in the middle of a such neighborhood so that the integral is nonzero. Therefore I would like to know if the claim holds more generally for not continuous functions. Or for all continuous functions, not necessarily with finitely many zeros.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Let $\theta\rightarrow 0$. Is that not enough?

Comment: Hi Bob! Thank you a lot for your comment! Could you argue a bit more? Maybe it is a good path indeed.

Comment: I guess you will need to exclude the case where $g$ is allowed to have countably number of non-zero points which these points have zero measure, so you will need continuity. Or your requirement on $g$ changes to $g(z) = 0$ almost everywhere

Comment: I agree with you. It would be enough indeed $g(z)=0$ almost everywhere for my purposes.

Comment: Sketch of proof: suppose $g$ Is not the zero function, is continuous and has finitely many fluctuations above and below zeros. Consider the biggest neighbour of $0 \in B$ such that $g > 0$ (could be also negative, doesn’t change reasoning). If $g$ is zero around 0, then take the neighbourhood starting from the point where $g$ is nonzero. Such a neighbourhood exists as $g$ is continuous and nonzero. Then $B$ will have the form $B=[0, y)$. Then $\int_{0}^{y} g(z) d \mu_y (z) > 0$ which is not possible. Thus $g$ must be zero up to $y$. Repeat this procedure for the finitely many oscillations.